# Check if input is equal to x and y then print

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I'm trying to get this example code to work:

```
a = ("good ")
b = ("morning")
z = input("Hi: ")
z
if z == "hello":
    print("good day!")
elif z == a and b:
    print("Good Night")
else:
   print("nope")
```

So I want it to print "Good Night" if the typed input is "good morning" (a and b) but it's not doing that. Instead it's printing "nope". What's the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: `and` is not the correct operator for string concatenation. I think you mean `elif z == a + b:`.

Comment: thanks that is what i meant, what if i want it have no specific order though, example if z == b + a doing the same as if z == a + b

Comment: @Yukon `elif z == a + b or z == b + a:`

Comment: The brackets on the assignment of a and b are redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join a and b strings as when you have the condition a and b it looks for making it true as a and b not by joining them! So you can do a + " " + b instead of a and b in the condition!

Answer (score 0):

Writing `a and b` is equivalent to check whether `a` is a non-empty string, which is True. This then returns `b`. But `z` is not equal to `b` so it fails. You probably intended to concatenate them, which is done with the `+` symbol for strings. Change that if statement to:

```
elif z == a + b:
    print("Good Night")
```

---

If you want to ignore the order you can do:

```
elif (z == a + b) or (z == b + a):
    print("Good Night")
```

Comment: `a and b` will never be `True`, it will be the first of the strings that allows Python to decide the truthiness of the expression. So, `'a' and 'b'` evaluates to `'b'`, `'' and 'b'` and `'a' and ''` both evaluate to `''`.

Answer (score 0):

The `and` doesn't concatenate (aka join) the strings like you think it does. It a boolean operator is used as the logical-and. Like others have suggested, you can concatenate them using `+`, but your a string has a space at the end, so if it's the reverse order (`morning good`), it won't work. Maybe use something like this:

```
a = "good" # notice the trailing space is not there
b = "morning"

if (z == (a + " " + b) or z == (b + " " + a)):
    # rest of your code...
```

or if you're into the fancy new f strings, you can use this in your if statement condition:

```
(z == (f'{a} {b}') or z == (f'{b} {a}'))
```

Hope that helps!